# Tecra Z50-C Touchpad: 2 Fingers scroll results in spurious middle click and right click

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, multi-touch, toshiba

Using ubuntu 16.04 freshly installed, the touchpad is unusable when using the scrolling with 2 fingers. Is there anyway to use another driver or a generic one (seems that the one used during the ubuntu install is working).

Here is my `xinput -list` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

After investigiating I found that

[Enable two-finger scrolling on ALPS touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24156/enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-alps-touchpad) which helps to fix the issue.

```
sudo echo "options psmouse proto=imps" > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf 

modprobe -r psmouse

modprobe psmouse
```